# How to grant connection and connect to phpmyadmin on server via mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have having issues and am not sure what I'm missing...

I have uploaded php files onto my server (ex. www.example.com) that I know work because I had them on xampp and used them through the phpmyadmin on xampp via mysql. Although, now that I have changed the mysqli_connect to:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("123.123.12.12","user", "pass", "dbname");
```

It gives me this error: Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (HY000/2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on ...

I have done some research, and I am seeing a lot of mentions about giving this connection access?? like granting remote access? I don't know how to grant access with the server I am on. I would like to figure out how to use mysql/phpmyadmin to use the pages I have created effectively.

Where would I grant remote access if that is the case??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to check is if the mysql server is running in `123.123.12.12`.  If the mysql server is running then the next thing to check would be that the server has port `1433` (in case of default) allowed in firewall.  The final thing to check is your `mysql.users` table,  if the `user` has either `123.123.12.12` or `%` in the `host` column.

If the first two checks are okay and you are searching for a way to grant privileges to this user from `123.123.12.12` then you can do the following:

```
grant all privileges on dbname.* to ‘user’@'123.123.12.12';
```

You would run this command in `mysql` prompt in the MySQL server.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It wasn't so much the connection, as it was the information given. I was trying to input the wrong information so it wasn't granting me connection. (username, password and db_name) I was having a hard time because of the Admin Panel not being directional. I just had to edit user/pass information to a specific database, and it worked. (using DirectAdmin)